# Wrong local time breaks file sync algorithm?

Tags: time, architecture, synchronization, cloud, data-synchronization

I am working on a cloud file sync application and an issue that comes up for users is the local time on the users computer being wrong. I use timestamps for tracking changes on each file to check which file is newer, but when someone's computer time is set to say 2005 or even an hour earlier or ahead of the right time and they make changes without being connected to the internet, when they then sync at a later date the time stamp for each file is wrong and overrides the very data they are trying to save.

Getting a timestamp from a time server like nist.gov can only happen when a user is connected to the internet, but if changes are made when the user is offline there is no way to get the right time. I was thinking about putting a counter to track changes to files in addition to a timestamp, but that doesnt work because multiple changes mess that up.

Comment: Sounds like you need version vectors, or some variation of them https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_vector

Comment: CMIS has a concept called change token...which changes if any changes to file/folders are made in server http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/cmis-spec-v1.0-errata-01-os-complete.html#_Toc243905432...change token can be used in client side to compare...date based comparison is never reliable...

Comment: @Joni Thank you, would a version clock work better since I am currently using timestamps?

Comment: @saurav are change tokens the same thing as version vectors?